# How to modify "[Product] has been added to your cart" in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters

I would like to change the "Product has been added to your cart." text  for variable products to include the variation.

For example if I added a size 7 Shoe to my cart it should say: "Shoe in Size 7 was added to your cart"

What do I have to edit to change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'my_add_to_cart_function', 10, 2 ); 

function my_add_to_cart_function( $message, $product_id ) { 
    $message = sprintf(esc_html__('« %s » has been added by to your cart.','woocommerce'), get_the_title( $product_id ) ); 
    return $message; 
}
```

The above code will help you to change the message. Since by knowing the hook `wc_add_to_cart_message` you can improve the code

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that code online but I'm not sure how to incorporate the product variation.

Comment: Will update answer for that soon. @harvey

Answer (score 0):

```
 add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_wc_add_to_cart_message', 10, 2 ); 

 function custom_wc_add_to_cart_message( $message, $product_id ) { 

 $message = sprintf( '%s has been added to your selection.', get_the_title( $product_id ) ); 

 return $message; 

 }
```

Hope this will help you:)